# How to catch exceptions With WebOS' AjaxCall

Tags: webos

I'm developing a WebOS 2.x app with mojo framework. I use [`Foundations.Comms.AjaxCall`](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/javascript-libraries/foundations/foundations-comms-ajax-call.html) to make ajax request. It goes well when everything is OK. However, when the call fails or the server response an error, I can't catch the error information.

I have tried this:

```
var f = AjaxCall.get(url);
f.then(successHandler, failureHandler);
```

and this:

```
var f = AjaxCall.get(url);
f.onError(failureHandler);
f.then(successHandler);
```

neither of them works. `failureHandler` is never called when there is an error.

Is there any way to be informed when there is an error?

Comment: Mojo apps don't automatically have access to the Foundations code.  Did you follow the guides at https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/javascript-libraries/foundations.html#using-foundations to load those scripts?

Comment: Yes I did follow the guides. The problem is `successHandler` works well when the request succeeds, but neither `successHandler` nor `failureHandler` be called when the request fails.

Answer (score 1):

In my Mojo apps I used Ajax.Request

I defined the onComplete handler like this:

```
onComplete: function(resp) {
  var resultCode = resp.getStatus();
  if ((resultCode > 0) && (resultCode < 200)) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
```